# Meaning of "...an otherwise + object"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Amy Lee is outstanding because she fronts **an otherwise male rock group** (Evanescence).

I don't understand properly the whole phrase and what does "an otherwise male rock group" especially the word "an otherwise" here precisely mean?

Comment: Hi, Jane - did you check [the dictionary definition for *otherwise*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/otherwise)?  (A hint: look at definition 3)

Answer (score 2):

*Except for her*, the band consists of males.

> There were mother-of-pearl buttons on her otherwise simple blouse.

In that usage above, where it modifies an adjective, **otherwise**  alludes to a fact implicit in an earlier clause. In the example with the blouse, the implicit fact is "mother-of-pearl buttons are not simple, they are ornate".

**otherwise** can be paraphrased as *in all other respects*.

There were [ornate] mother-of-pearl buttons on her blouse, which was *in all other respects* not ornate, but simple.

> It had a new front door, but the house was **otherwise dilapidated**. The windows were broken, paint was peeling everywhere, and many shingles were missing from the roof.

As an adverb the word **otherwise** can be placed directly before the predicated adjective, after it, or at the head of the clause:

> Flight #2343 is 30 minutes late, but the airline is otherwise on-time.
>
> Flight #2343 is 30 minutes late, but the airline is  on-time otherwise.
>
> Flight #2343 is 30 minutes late, but otherwise the airline is on-time.
>
> Flight #2343 is 30 minutes late; otherwise the airline is on-time.

Answer (score 2):

In older English, the word ***wise*** meant ***manner of doing something.*** If you wanted to say that something happened a certain way, you might say, ***It happened on this wise.*** In the old King James Bible (1611 A.D.), we find this in St. Matthew's Gospel: ***Now the birth of Jesus Christ was on this wise...***, whereas today we would say something like, ***This is how the birth of Jesus Christ took place.***

While that's archaic, ***wise*** combined with other words to create words we still use, such as ***likewise,*** meaning in a similar fashion, or ***otherwise,*** which means in a different fashion. Otherwise is tricky because it can be an an adverb as well as an adjective describing a potentially different situation:

Adverb: Move quickly, ***otherwise*** we shall miss the train.

Adjective: If things were ***otherwise,*** we would have known by now.